# Mocha Typescript test doesn't print Console.log

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I have setup my test using mocha, chai, typescript, in Node:

```
import chai = require('chai');
import chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
import ReadLine = require('readline');
import FS = require('fs');

before((done) => {
    chai.should();
    chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
    done();
});


describe("Test", function() {
    this.timeout(20000);
    let testFile: string [] = [];

    before((done) => {
        let lineReader = ReadLine.createInterface({
            input: FS.createReadStream("MyFile.txt")
        });

        lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
            testFile.push(line);
        });
        done();
    });
    it("test", () => {
        for(let i=0;i<testFile.length;i++){
            let curLine = testFile[i];
            console.log(curLine);
        }
    }).timeout(30000);
});
```

Then I run my test like this:

```
C:\Repository\Folder>npm test

> Test@0.0.1 test C:\Repository\Folder
> mocha -r ts-node/register -R spec test/**/*.ts



  Test
    √ test


  1 passing (16ms)
```

So it does seem to pass, but it's not printing out to console, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this piece of code:

```
lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    testFile.push(line);
});
done();
```

Your ReadLine reader works asynchronously. You attach a listener, and before any line is read, `done()` is already called as it's the next entry in the Event Loop.

To fix it, wait for the reader to close:

```
import chai = require('chai');
import chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
import ReadLine = require('readline');
import FS = require('fs');

before((done) => {
    chai.should();
    chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
    done();
});


describe("Test", function() {
    this.timeout(20000);
    let testFile: string [] = [];

    before((done) => {
        let lineReader = ReadLine.createInterface({
            input: FS.createReadStream("MyFile.txt")
        });

        lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
            testFile.push(line);
        });
        linereader.on('close', () => done()); // <===== 
    });
    it("test", () => {
        for(let i=0;i<testFile.length;i++){
            let curLine = testFile[i];
            console.log(curLine);
        }
    }).timeout(30000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use done() after for loop:

```
it("test", (done) => {
    for(let i=0;i<testFile.length;i++){
        let curLine = testFile[i];
        console.log(curLine);
    }

  done();
}).timeout(30000);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that made no difference.

Comment: In `before()` move `done();` inside `lineReader.on('line')` callback just after `testFile.push(line);` in order to wait until `testFile` will be set